# Writing on top of a long arrow

Tags: arrows

[image]

I want to make the arrow in the numerator longer, like the one in the denominator and write `$x$` on top of it. I'm using the package `mathtools`.

```
\[
    H_{1}(K_1)=\frac{\textrm{ker}(R \xrightarrow{x} R)}{\textrm{im}(0 \longrightarrow R)} \cong \textrm{ker}(R \longrightarrow R)= \frac{R}{xR}.
\]
```

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). // By the way: [`\[ ... \]` is better than `$$ ... $$`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for entering math mode.

Comment: You can do this: `\xrightarrow{~x~}` or this `\xrightarrow{\,\,x\,\,}`

Comment: Thank you everyone. Appreciate all the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(`memoir` is unrelated, just my goto class)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}
\begin{document}
\[
H_1(K_1) = \frac{\ker(R\xrightarrow{x} R)}{\im(0\to R)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Yeah - You wrote in your query that "I want to make the arrow in the numerator longer, like the one in the denominator..." Yet you accepted an answer that works by performing the exact opposite operation: *Making the arrow in the denominator shorter* - as short, in fact, as the arrow in the numerator of your original posting. Should you maybe rewrite your stated objective to avoid confusion as to what you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you load the `extarrows` package and use that package's `\xlongrightarrow` macro.

Aside: Since "ker" and "im" are math operators, do make them into objects of type `mathop`. The macro `\ker` is pre-defined; it's straightforward (using the `\DeclareMathoperator` tool) to set up `\im` as a math-op object as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,extarrows}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
\begin{document}
\[
    H_{1}(K_1)=\frac{\ker(R\xlongrightarrow{x}R)}{\im(0\longrightarrow R)} 
    \cong \ker(R\longrightarrow R)= \frac{R}{xR}.
\]
\end{document}
```